# Why can't I setup CancellationToken?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I'm trying to write a test for a class and it seems that I can't setup the *CheckLoginAsync* method of mine. This *CheckLoginAsync* method has 2 parameters. The second parameter is an optional one and looks like this:

```
    public async Task CheckLoginAsync(ISettings userSettings, CancellationToken? cancellationToken = null);
```

The setup code is the following:

```
        backendFacadeMock = new Mock<BackendFacade>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        backendFacadeMock
            .Setup(bf => bf.Initialize())
            .Returns(() => Task.FromResult(0));
        backendFacadeMock
            .Setup(bf => bf.CheckLoginAsync(It.IsAny<ISettings>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken?>()))
            .Returns(() => Task.FromResult(0));

        nullBackendFacadeMock = new Mock<IBackendFacade>(MockBehavior.Strict);


        backendFacadeFactoryMock = new Mock<IBackendFacadeFactory>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        backendFacadeFactoryMock
            .Setup(bf => bf.CreateBackendFacade())
            .Returns(() => backendFacadeMock.Object);
        backendFacadeFactoryMock
            .Setup(bf => bf.CreateNullBackendFacade())
            .Returns(() => nullBackendFacadeMock.Object);
```

The code that is being tested is the following:

```
    private async Task<IBackendFacade> CreateBackendFacade()
    {
        IBackendFacade backendFacade = _backendFacadeFactory.CreateBackendFacade();
        try
        {              
            await backendFacade.CheckLoginAsync(_userSettings);            
            await backendFacade.Initialize();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            backendFacade = _backendFacadeFactory.CreateNullBackendFacade();
        }

        return backendFacade;
    }
```

The *CheckLoginAsync* invocation in the code mentioned above throws the following exception:

```
IBackendFacade.CheckLoginAsync(Mock<de.cas.officeintegration.outlook.core.application.ISettings:00000001>.Object, null) invocation failed with mock behavior Strict.
All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.
```

The test itself:

```
    [Test]
    public async Task GetBackendFacadeAsync_NoException_ReturnsABackendFacadeObject()
    {
        var backendFacadeProvider = new BackendFacadeProvider(backendFacadeFactoryMock.Object, userSettingsMock.Object);

        IBackendFacade backendFacade = await backendFacadeProvider.GetBackendFacadeAsync();

        Assert.AreSame(backendFacadeMock.Object, backendFacade);
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the interesting thing is that I've already tried using It.IsAny<CancellationToken>() and null, too but the same things happens and throws the same exception.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. This will assist in narrowing the problem and finding potential solutions.